# Jasper reports not exporting report

Tags: jasper-reports

My code not throwing any exception and also report not generating, is there any issue in code

```
Connection con = getConnection();
        HashMap<String,Object> param = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        try {
        param.put("order_id", 202);
        InputStream employeeReportStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Invoice.jrxml");

        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(employeeReportStream);

        JasperPrint jasperPrint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport , param,con);


        JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, new FileOutputStream("report.pdf")); 

        exporter.exportReport();

        System.out.println("done printing");

    }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if (con != null) {
                try { con.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }
```

this is my output

Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
done printing

Comment: `report not generating` - What does it mean?

Comment: exportReport() generate a report and save it on disk.

Answer (score 0):

change the jdbc driver class name of the database connection, `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`